# How to convert hourly solar irradiation values to hourly values between 0 and 1 calculated per day

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe `df` with data about hourly (`df$Datetime`) solar irradiation (`df$Irradiance`) during 9 months. As an example:

```
df<- data.frame(Datetime=c("2019-07-30 00:00:00","2019-07-30 01:00:00","2019-07-30 02:00:00","2019-07-30 03:00:00","2019-07-30 04:00:00","2019-07-30 05:00:00","2019-07-30 06:00:00","2019-07-30 07:00:00","2019-07-30 08:00:00","2019-07-30 09:00:00","2019-07-30 10:00:00","2019-07-30 11:00:00","2019-07-30 12:00:00","2019-07-30 13:00:00","2019-07-30 14:00:00","2019-07-30 15:00:00","2019-07-30 16:00:00","2019-07-30 17:00:00","2019-07-30 18:00:00","2019-07-30 19:00:00","2019-07-30 20:00:00","2019-07-30 21:00:00"),
                Irradiance=c(0,0,0,0,0,1354,8574,15698,35874,87569,148632,248254,358326,387520,312542,249874,189325,102458,59632,24879,1003,0))

df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="utz")

df

              Datetime Irradiance
1  2019-07-30 00:00:00          0
2  2019-07-30 01:00:00          0
3  2019-07-30 02:00:00          0
4  2019-07-30 03:00:00          0
5  2019-07-30 04:00:00          0
6  2019-07-30 05:00:00       1354
7  2019-07-30 06:00:00       8574
8  2019-07-30 07:00:00      15698
9  2019-07-30 08:00:00      35874
10 2019-07-30 09:00:00      87569
11 2019-07-30 10:00:00     148632
12 2019-07-30 11:00:00     248254
13 2019-07-30 12:00:00     358326
14 2019-07-30 13:00:00     387520
15 2019-07-30 14:00:00     312542
16 2019-07-30 15:00:00     249874
17 2019-07-30 16:00:00     189325
18 2019-07-30 17:00:00     102458
19 2019-07-30 18:00:00      59632
20 2019-07-30 19:00:00      24879
21 2019-07-30 20:00:00       1003
22 2019-07-30 21:00:00          0
```

I would like to create a new variable called `LightIntensity` that ranges between 0 and 1 every day. The hour in which there is the maximum irradiance the new value for the new variable will be 1, and for the hours where there is no irradiance, the new value will be 0. The tricky point is that the irradiance change over the year, so I need to calculate the hourly `LightIntensity` by day.

Below there is an example of what I would expect. In this case, I just divided the hourly irradiance (`df$Datetime`) by the maximum irradiance of this day (`387520`).

```
df$LightIntensity <- df$Irradiance/387520

df

              Datetime Irradiance LightIntensity
1  2019-07-30 00:00:00          0    0.000000000
2  2019-07-30 01:00:00          0    0.000000000
3  2019-07-30 02:00:00          0    0.000000000
4  2019-07-30 03:00:00          0    0.000000000
5  2019-07-30 04:00:00          0    0.000000000
6  2019-07-30 05:00:00       1354    0.003494013
7  2019-07-30 06:00:00       8574    0.022125310
8  2019-07-30 07:00:00      15698    0.040508877
9  2019-07-30 08:00:00      35874    0.092573287
10 2019-07-30 09:00:00      87569    0.225972853
11 2019-07-30 10:00:00     148632    0.383546656
12 2019-07-30 11:00:00     248254    0.640622419
13 2019-07-30 12:00:00     358326    0.924664533
14 2019-07-30 13:00:00     387520    1.000000000
15 2019-07-30 14:00:00     312542    0.806518373
16 2019-07-30 15:00:00     249874    0.644802849
17 2019-07-30 16:00:00     189325    0.488555429
18 2019-07-30 17:00:00     102458    0.264394096
19 2019-07-30 18:00:00      59632    0.153881090
20 2019-07-30 19:00:00      24879    0.064200557
21 2019-07-30 20:00:00       1003    0.002588254
22 2019-07-30 21:00:00          0    0.000000000
```

However, I don't know how to do it when my dataframe spans more than one day (in my case, around 240 days). How should I do to create a variable called `LightIntensity` taking into account the maximum irradiance per day?

Note: I would prefer to learn to do it with the `data.table` language, however, other ways are useful for me.

Comment: Divide by the maximum `df$LightIntensity <- df$Irradiance/max(df$Irradiance)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute the `LightIntensity` by day, use `ave`.

```
df2$LightIntensity <- ave(df2$Irradiance, as.Date(df2$Datetime),
                          FUN = function(x) x/max(x))
```

**Data**

Since the data posted in the question only runs through one day, I will add another 5 days. The Irradiance is similar to the first day's.

```
set.seed(1234)
DT <- df$Datetime + rep(86400, nrow(df))*rep(0:4, each = nrow(df))
Irr <- round(abs(jitter(rep(df$Irradiance, 5))))
df2 <- rbind(df, data.frame(Datetime = DT, Irradiance = Irr))
rm(DT, Irr)
```

Comment: That's perfect @Rui Barradas. Just one note: when I reproduce your dataframe example (`df2`), I get twice the day `2019-07-30`, and then the script uses the day with the maximum Irradiance and one of the two `2019-07-30` get a value for the hour with the maximum irradiance slightly below from 1. But the script works perfectly. Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr` option:

```
df %>%
  group_by(as.Date(Datetime)) %>%
  mutate(LightIntensity = Irradiance/max(Irradiance))
```